Is there a way to bind event in dynamically rendered components in angular using templates?
I am using below code to render my components dynamically  -
    @for(item of list(); track $index){
    <!-- dynamic rendering using ng-container -->
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentToRender(); inputs: item;" />
}

Is there a way to bind events using any property of ng-container similar to input?
I have alreay searched the internet and those solutions suggesting to use  @ViewChild but I want to know if any solution exists which uses only templates for event binding.

Yes, you can pass in the method you want to call as a property and execute the method inside the component code. The property contains the callback, you might lack strict typing, but you can fix this by providing a proper type definition to the input signal.
Parent:
HTML:
@for(item of list(); track $index){
  <!-- dynamic rendering using ng-container -->
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentToRender(); inputs: {item, callback: callback.bind(this)};" />
}

TS:
callback(input: string) {
  console.log(this, input, 'child calling parent');
}

Full Code:
import { Component, input, signal, InputSignal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    child: {{item().test}}
    <button (click)="callback()('data from child')">call parent method</button>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  item: InputSignal<any> = input.required();
  callback: InputSignal<(callbackProp: string) => void> = input.required();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child, CommonModule],
  template: `
    @for(item of list(); track $index){
      <!-- dynamic rendering using ng-container -->
      <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentToRender(); inputs: {item, callback: callback.bind(this)};" />
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  list = signal([{ test: 1 }]);
  componentToRender = signal(Child);

  callback(input: string) {
    console.log(this, input, 'child calling parent');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
